# Scope inside jQuery load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am having a problem with the scope. Sorry for this noobish question.

I am trying to append images to a parent div with jQuery, but don't know how to pass the variable "theParent" to the load function.

```js
// inside a this.each loop

    var theParent = $(this).parent('div.parent'); 

    var img = $("<img />")
                .attr('src', '/path/img.jpg')
                .error(function(){ console.log('error'); })
                .load(function(){
                    img.addClass('myClass'); // <-- not working plz help
                    theParent.append(img); // <-- not working plz help
                    });
```

Comment: Can you post the entire this.each loop? Looks like a problem with waiting for .load to complete before the next iteration.

Comment: There don't appear to be any scope issues here.

Comment: This seems to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/k2Kb7/1/ (although not sure of your looping)

Comment: Thanks you all. 
roXon's answer helped me: i got confused by all the $(this) vs. this since it's a function inside a loop inside a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/itepap/3/edit)**</kbd>

`$(this).addClass('myClass');` would work but use:

```
var img = $("<img />", {
          "src"   : '/images/favicon.png',
          "class" : 'myClass'
      })
      .error(function(){ console.log('error'); })
      .load(function(){
                img.appendTo( theParent ); 
      });
```

Comment: How is `img` undefined? The `load` callback will execute later, so when it tries to resolve the reference to `img` **later**, it should be available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var theParent = $(this).parent('div.parent'); 

    var img = $("<img />", {
      src: '/path/img.jpg',
      "class": 'myClass' 
    }).appendTo(theParent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ "this" is the object the load event is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
$('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" class="myClass" src="theImg.png" />')
```